# Overclocking a nVIDIA GTX 660M GPU?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

I have a MSI GE60 0ND laptop with a GTX 660M GPU. When I play games like Minecraft or Portal 2, the core clock is stable at 835 MHz. Recently I tried to overclock it using MSI Afterburner but it wouldn't let me change the voltages or the clock speed no matter what I tried. Various Google searches yielded solutions that all didn't work. Is there any way I can overclock the GPU?
Further Info: I have the nVIDIA 310.70 drivers and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

It´s not possible to change the voltage, period! The things you should be able to change is the core clock and memory clock. If the core and memory are locked i dont know what you should do. Maby it´s because you run Windows 8? I have the exact same laptop running Windows 7 and i can clock core and memory. By the way make sure to use a cooling pad when you clock the msi because the cooling system is not the best on the msi ge60.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly not recommend doing that. That is quite dangerous. Overclocking a laptop GPU can lead to some serious overheating. Don't do it. But if you do, do a test with Furmark to make sure it's stable. If it's going above 80C then stop overclocking. Try Asus GPU Tweak and see if that works. You can't change the voltage because the computer isn't made for draining more power than it is, being a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

today gpu performance is "mostly" determined by things other than clock speed. a higher class gpu has more unified shaders to process shaders and you can't make a lower class gpu catch up with the performance just by increasing clock speed, like we used to do in 2000s. even if you can overclock, your computer is likely to freeze. don't do it.